# Print content of a web page issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I've no idea what's wrong with my code, but it does print nothing to stdout, although there is some content as shown in a debugger.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <afx.h>
#include <afxinet.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "wininet.h"

using namespace std;



void DisplayPage(LPCTSTR pszURL)
{
   CInternetSession session(_T("Mozilla/5.0"));
   CStdioFile* pFile = NULL;
   pFile = session.OpenURL(pszURL);
   CString str = _T("");


   while ( pFile->ReadString(str) )
   {
       wcout << str.GetString() << endl;  // <-- here I expect some output, get nothing
                                            //     not even newline !
   }

   delete pFile;
   session.Close();
}


// --- MAIN ---
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DisplayPage( _T("http://www.google.com") );

    cout << "done !" << endl;
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

It is a console project. Console window pops up with message *"done !"* displayed only.

Comment: Can you post a complete, short program that doesn't work? See http://sscce.org for details about why I ask.

Comment: Are you sure your application is a console application and you have a valid console?

Comment: Code example completed. It is a valid console application. If I use cout instead of wcout in DisplayPage function then pointer addresses are printed not strings.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody interested the issue was caused by non-OEM characters recieved from a web page trying to write to the default console (expecting OEM chars, translating mode). At the first non-OEM character std::wcout stops processing.
Either set the console to binary mode or convert recieved string to the appropriate encoding *before* sending to standard output.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

...
int old_transmode = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
std::wcout << str.GetString() << std::endl;    // print wide string characters
...
_set_mode(_fileno(stdout), old_transmode);    // restore original console output mode
```

Comment: I have to add, the whole issue is caused by CStdioFile::ReadString expects stream of wide strings (ie. UTF-16) and this behaviour is not documented and can not be changed. If supplied with other encoding like UTF-8 in case of a webpage, content gets garbled. So either above workaround to avoid content translation or use CStdioFile::Read(void* lpBuf, UINT nCount) instead.